# First time using i.segment.uspo in GRASS

Tags: grass-7.0, image-segmentation

I am using the module i.segment.uspo in GRASS for the first time and I wanted to know if anyone here haws experience with that add-on in GRASS so I can get some hints on how to use it more efficiently, because I could use i.segment but I feel like it wouldn't be the same because, for once, I don't know how to properly set up meanshift. So, can anyone help me understand better how i.segment.uspo works or are you as new to this as I am?

P.S If someone could point me to some examples, or even share, other than the ones that are in the documentation file, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first set you region of interest with this command:

```
g.region -d vector=myregion@name_of_grasssession save=myregion1
```

This command creates region of interest bordered with vector layer placed in grass database called myregion1

In the next step you are able to run optimization process of segmentation:

```
i.segment.uspo group=myimage@name_of_grass_session regions=myregion1@name_of_grass output=parameters.csv segment_map=ortho_uspo threshold_start=0.02 threshold_stop=0.21 threshold_step=0.02 minsizes=5,10,15 number_best=5 processes=4 memory=4000
```

It runs pretty well because it is optimized for parallel processing. After algorithm is complete you will be able to find .csv file if you run windows:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

I plan to use this tool in my Ph.D. thesis and I have started using this tool so far just like you. If I discover something useful I will share my experience.

Comment: I am writing a script in shell with i.segment.uspo for my undergrad thesis. But I am stuck at a loop and I can't seem to export a step-based segment-map

Answer (score 1):

Other than the documentation and this article (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315897308_An_Open-Source_Semi-Automated_Processing_Chain_for_Urban_Object-Based_Classification) there's nothing else I could find.